# Suppressing "pink" validation of HTML5 <input type"number"> on iOS

Tags: ios, html, textfield

I am using the "type=number" for my  tag on a HTML5 web app for iOS.  The behaviour that I want is to have the numeric side of the alphanumeric keyboard on iOS show up when the user selects the textfield to edit, which it currently does.

The problem is that when a number with a decimal point is put into the field the background of the textfield turns a pink colour on an iOS device. Is there anyway of shutting this off or working around it?

[image: pink validation]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `novalidate` attribute to the `form`.

```
<form novalidate>
     <input type="number" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) Still getting a pink colour :( And it changed my page layout.